# How to use breakpoints

Tags: debugging

I am trying to learn the basics of debugging using SEGGER. I am using a very simple blinky example to start learning debugging.

I have declare and initialize two variables x & y. When I run the debugger and use the "watch" window to monitor the value of each variable, I can see the y variable but neither the x or i variables.. It sais "symbol not found" as shown on [screenshot_69](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qbZU.png)​

The strange thing is that if I initialize x=0 then I can see the x variable on "watch" window as shown on [screenshot_70](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq1IP.png). But again I cannot see the i variable.

Moreover if I delete both x and y variables then I can monitor i variable while debugging as shown in [screenshot_71](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6rNj.png).

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong with the breakpoints.. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

​Ok I figured out what was going wrong,

I was compiling in release mode :) After switching to debugging mode everything was fixed!!

I lost two hours of searching yesterday  but that was I good lesson since now I have a clearer view of release and debugging modes.

So in general while developing a firmware you have to compile in debugging mode and as soon as you're ready to flash the firmware to the target you have to compile into release mode for optimization right?​